# Android GestureLibrary save and gestureLibrary is readOnly

Tags: android

I am posting this question after a lot of google searching
and after looking at the gesture builder source code, which I am using to create and save gestures. 
The thing is my gesture Library that I am loading from a raw file gets loaded correctly but when I try to save a new gesture to it, it failed and the save method returned `false`. 
When I checked `gestureLibrary.isReadOnly()` it also returned `true`, does that mean I can't save to it, since it's read only? 
I am using all the permissions to write on external storage and internal storage.
Any help ?!

Comment: Hope the below answer is a fix, is it?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to save the Gesture file present in the res folder i.e res/raw, you can't as It is not allowed to edit the application resources in run time.

Hence you can place the gesture file in assets and then save it in the phone where the app is going to be installed and then try to ave using save method of GestureLibrary class, this solved my problem.

code to store an asset file to internal memory:

```
File gestureFile=new File(directory.getPath(),"gesture");
try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("gestures");

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(gestureFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            //read from is to buffer
            while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) !=-1){
                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            is.close();
            //flush OutputStream to write any buffered data to file
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

code to save:

```
mLibrary1=GestureLibraries.fromFile(new File(directory.getPath(),"gesture"));
mLibrary1.addGesture(strTemp,gesture);
            boolean temp= mLibrary1.save();
            if(temp){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Not Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Sorry for the late reply though.